# ckeditor styles conflicting with bootstrap styles

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

In my zinnia-blog app, i am using django-ckeditor to style the 'entries' from admin. Also my site is designed on the foundation of twitter-bootstrap. The problem is that if I made a style change to any entry in the blog it is affecting the styles of whole page. I dont know what might be the exact reason for this, whether it is due to any CSS conflict is happening. Can you please suggest any possible solutions ?

Comment: Please post the HTML and CSS for the blog entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding a class to each of my ckeditor authored content areas, and then doing some reset within this class.  For example (scss):

```
.ckeditor-content {
  [class*="span"] {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  color: #000000;
}
```

Any element specific styles added by the user via CKEditor could then override these, but this at least handles the case where no element style has been added and Bootstrap (or your own css) is applying unwanted formatting.